# C# печать уменьшенных изображений в высоком разрешении

Tags: c#, печать, itextsharp

Что нужно: открыть скан А4 (всегда будут использоваться сканы), уменьшить его размеры в 2 раза, разместить на 1/4 листа А4 и поместить результат в pdf.

Имеется скан в разрешении 2464:3424 и 300dpi, формат jpg.
Использую библиотеку itextsharp. Проблема в том, что качество печати довольно плохое, зернистое, притом что у меня лазерный принтер с 1200dpi и высокое разрешение картинки (как я думаю). Печатаю в помощью Foxit Reader, с 1200dpi в настройках принтера. Основной код:

```
public void CreatePdf(string path, System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    var doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
    var a4Size = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
    doc.SetPageSize(a4Size);

    var width = 297;
    var height = 421;
    // Половины от PageSize.A4
    _neededSize = new Rectangle(width, height);

    var table = new PdfPTable(2);

    var img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    img.ScaleToFit(_neededSize);
    table.AddCell(img);

    doc.Add(table);
    doc.Close();
}
```

Считывание картинки происходит так:

```
var img = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

Пробовал сразу печатать средствами C#, качество не повысилось. Хотя "по ТЗ" должна быть pdf.

В чем может быть проблема, в недостаточном разрешении исходного материала? На англоязычных форумах советуют повысить разрешении картинок, но я не понимаю, что имеется ввиду: подсовывать картинки более качественные или программно какие-то манипуляции производить.

Но в pdf файле потери качества нет. И pdf получается такого же размера (в Кб я имею ввиду), что и картинка. То есть правильно ли я понимаю, что foxit производит сжатие перед печатью? В таком случае, если ли способ улучшить этот результат? Обработать как-нибудь изображение?

Может быть стоит использовать другие библиотеки?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что код работает нормально: получается качественный четкий PDF-файл. Проблема возникает только при печати через Foxit Reader?

Comment: @defaultlocale Да, все верно.

Comment: А ручками печатать пробовали без каких-либо либ? У принтера есть и свои параметры...

Answer (score 1):

Включил мозг и попробовал распечатать скан с помощью "средства просмотра изображений" от Windows и MS Word (говорили в интернете, что неплохо сжимает для печати). Получил примерно одинаковое качество с моей версией. И хотя это не дает ответа на вопрос об улучшении качества, этот вопрос можно считать закрытым - изображение печаталось так как должно было.

Видимо решение моей проблемы лежит в преобразовании изображения для улучшения качества ещё до того, как оно будет помещено в PDF.

Спасибо и извиняюсь за потраченное время.